# React Native - Update text after clicking button

Tags: react-native

I want to update the text after clicking button.

[image: change text]

But couldn't find a way to do this.

The code is like:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const state = {
    user: 'test',
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{state.user}'s profile</Text>
      <Button
        title="Change user param"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.dispatch({
            ...CommonActions.setParams({ user: 'Wojtek' }),
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[Expo example](https://snack.expo.io/@g903/route-prop-reference-%7C-react-navigation?session_id=snack-session-4rZdHYlbA&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=226xlhvyy1&theme=light)

I've tried `navigation.setParams()` and `this.setState()`, they couldn't work with the code I attached above.

Comment: This issue is not related to React Navigation so the title is misleading. I recommend a better understand of React Native components and State management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use hooks in functional components. So the code would be something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState('test');
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{user}'s profile</Text>
      <Button
        title="Change user param"
        onPress={() => setUser("keidakira") }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Check it's working at [Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@keidakida/route-prop-reference-%7C-react-navigation?session_id=snack-session-4rZdHYlbA&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=226xlhvyy1&theme=light)